# How can I get details about the device data provider (like Verizon/AT&T) of an iphone programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I am trying to create an ios application and I want to segment the users based on the data providers they are using, such as Verizon and AT&T. Is it possible to get this information programmatically from the ios application.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You should check the [`CTCarrier`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCarrier/index.html).

Just import `CoreTelephony` into your Swift file.

Then you can use the [`carrierName`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCarrier/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CTCarrier/carrierName) property to get the name of your carrier.

```
// Setup the Network Info and create a CTCarrier object
let networkInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
let carrier = networkInfo.subscriberCellularProvider

// Get carrier name
let carrierName = carrier.carrierName
```

Comment: It is the SIM card's operator name, is not unnecessary the current network's operator in using.

Comment: 'subscriberCellularProvider' was deprecated in iOS 12.0: Replaced by serviceSubscriberCellularProviders

Comment: For iOS 12, given the ability to have multiple SIM cards in some devices, Apple has depreciated 'subscriberCellularProvider' and replaced it with an array of cellularProviders, 'serviceSubscriberCellularProviders'. If unconcerned with CTCarrier selected, just use:  `let carrier = networkInfo.serviceSubscriberCellularProviders?.first?.value`

Comment: it just prints "Carrier" for me ;/

Answer (score 5):

Now that you can have multiple SIM cards, `subscriberCellularProvider` is deprecated in favor of `serviceSubscriberCellularProviders`. You can get an array of the providers with this:

```
let carriers = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo().serviceSubscriberCellularProviders?.values
```

---

In my case, I was checking to see if the user has an American phone number so they can text support instead of email. You can do that with this:

```
carriers.contains { $0.isoCountryCode?.lowercased() == "us" }
```

On my phone, I only have one SIM card, but this array returns two values and one has all nil properties so be sure to handle that if you are inspecting them.

Answer (score 3):

You will want to use the `CTCarrier` `carrierName` in the CoreTelephony framework: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCarrier/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CTCarrier/carrierName