# iOS: Determining which carrier an iPhone is locked to programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, carrier

I want to get the name of the carrier that the device is locked to programmatically,  I don’t know if the carrier is currently being used can be different with the carrier is locked to but i suppose that might be possible (for example maybe it is possible to use cellOperator Fido while locked to Bell since they’re actually the same underlying service).

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [How can I get details about the device data provider (like Verizon/AT&T) of an iphone programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28454344/how-can-i-get-details-about-the-device-data-provider-like-verizon-att-of-an-i)

Comment: Locked devices can be unlocked by the carrier and as far as I am aware you wouldn't know until you try and hit the carrier's activation server.

Comment: I am also looking for the same. Has anyone found a solution. If yes, then please tag me in the comment/answer.