# How to design choose the SIM and get a unique id in iOS while authentication?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, xcode

A) In android i can get the SIM details and can specifically choose the SIM for sending the OTP from that SIM. I have a sample screen which is possible to implement in Android.

I followed the link for ios [How can I get details about the device data provider (like Verizon/AT&T) of an iphone programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28454344/how-can-i-get-details-about-the-device-data-provider-like-verizon-att-of-an-i)

[https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/9171](http://how%20can%20i%20get%20phone%20number%20from%20swift?) This link states we cant get the SIM Phone numbers from device because of Apple Privacy policy

How to implement the same screen in iOS? Any alternative idea or help is appreciated

B) How to get the Unique id for authentication?

In Android we can get (IMEI+SIM Serial number) can be used for authentication but in iOS all these are restricted due to privacy . Instead it is  impossible to get UDID which is unique for every device. I know i can use vendor id for this:

```
UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString
```

But as the documentation says: `The value in this property remains the same while the app (or another app from the same vendor) is installed on the iOS device. The value changes when the user deletes all of that vendor’s apps from the device and subsequently reinstalls one or more of them.`

Since the vendor id changes when the user uninstalls the Application .So is it any way around to get a unique id other than Vendor ID for authentication which doesn't change and is unique all time?

Comment: a) maybe redesign screen and let user to enter the phone number himself?
b) no legal way to track if its unique device across installations

Comment: @NeilGaliaskarov can you post this as an answer so that i can upvote it? Thanks for this comment .. Please explain more about your b) comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to get SIM phone number?**

As it stated in the question, its not available to get the phone number due to the security reasons. I suggest you to have a textfield and let user to enter the numbers, so you can send the sms to verify it

**How to get the Unique id for authentication?**

You have two options here based on your deployment target needs:

1. Apple has come up with the [DeviceCheck](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck) framework in iOS 11.  Your app should use the DeviceCheck APIs to generate an ephemeral token that identifies a device. Your associated server combines this token with an authentication key that you receive from Apple and uses the result to request access to the per-device bits.
   Very intentionally by Apple, DeviceCheck tokens can not be used to identify the specific device.
   But you can try playing to get unique identifier for the iOS device state
2. Create your own unique ID and save it in the [keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8677177/1895729).

**References**

- WWDC 2017 — [Session 702](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/702/) — iOS, macOS, tvOS, watchOS
- [Apple Documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/accessing_and_modifying_the_per_device_data) — Access per-device, per-developer data that your associated server can use in its business logic.
- [Unique Identifier for the iOS Devices Article](https://codeburst.io/unique-identifier-for-the-ios-devices-590bb778290d)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer So is it better to use vendorIdentifier as of now ? because my app needs to support iOS versions below iOS 11 too and Device check framework is available only for iOS 11 +

Comment: `vendorIdentifier` is very unstable and I strongly not recommend you to use it. In my practice it has been changed even across app-updates.

Comment: so what you suggest to use instead of vendorIdentifier ?

Comment: Any help will be greatly appreciated. Is NSString *UUID = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]; still usable instead of vendorIdentifier?

Comment: Do you want it unique across installations? Imagine - user deletes the app and then reinstalls it, should you come up with the same id?

Comment: Yes and the user can register only on one device at a time. He can't register in multiple devices. So if i want unique across installations what to do? Please suggest .. And if in case i don't want unique across installations what to do? Please explain in both scenarios.

Comment: Long story short - you want be able to get unique id across installations especially lower than ios11...

Comment: before I do it, do you know any iOS applications which works as you want?

Comment: As of now no ... but the only requirement for me is to uniquely identify the device as android does. So that the user cannot register more than one device at the same time with deployment target iOS 9 and above

Comment: I update my answer with second option which might help you

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can we send that unique ID generated in second option to the server? Is there any chance of apple rejection?

Comment: No, you want be rejected, its a public api

Comment: thanks for the help once again. Regarding sim , is there any way to determine the SMS being is sent from the SIM which is present in our phone. Means if i want to send SMS with a phone number which is not in our phone , it shouldn't allow sending message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219166/discussion-between-neil-galiaskarov-and-fiona-shoff).